# Emplacing a thread object into a vector where the function is a member function and need return value

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector

```
std::atomic<unsigned int> sum(0);
std::vector<std::thread> myThreads;
MyBaseObj *myObj = new MyDerivedObject();
```

MyDerivedObject has a member function which is declared as follows:

```
unsigned int MyDerivedObject::DoSomething(unsigned int paramA, double paramB);
```

How can I launch this "DoSomething" method (and other methods with the same signature) in a thread, give it parameters, and add it's return value to "sum"?

I can do something like the following, but I cant figure out the syntax of how to emplace this into my vector.

```
auto threadFunc = [](std::function<unsigned int(MyBaseObj&,unsigned int,double)> memberFunc, 
                     MyBaseObj &myObj
                     unsigned int number1, 
                     double number 2) {
    sum += memberFunc(myObj,number1,number2);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find nullary (no argument) lambdas are best to pass to `std::thread`:

```
int number1=42;
double number2=3.14;
myThreads.emplace_back(
  [myObj,number1,number2,&sum]{
    sum += myObj->DoSomething(number1, number2);
  }
);
```

this creates a nullary lambda that captures everything it needs to (most by value, and `sum` by reference) with the code you want to write.

You could also do something like:

```
myThreads.emplace_back(
  [&sum](MyBaseObj *myObj, int number1, double number2){
    sum += myObj->DoSomething(number1, number2);
  }, myObj, number1, number2
);
```

where you use `thread`'s constructor to store the arguments, but I don't see the point.  Just capture them in the lambda.

Ok, there is a point -- prior to C++14, you couldn't move data into a lambda capture, while you could move data into a `std::thread` argument list.  However, MSVC screwed up the `std::thread` implementation in MSVC2013 (I don't know if anyone else did), so it (moving arguments in) won't work there anyhow.

Comment: I do like the stateless lambdas, thank you. However, is it possible to exclude the direct call to the member function? For example, i mean if the object had 20 different member functions with the same signature. I'd like to be able to use the same lambda.

Comment: @VictorStone oops, nullary lambda not stateless.  (A stateless lambda doesn't capture anything).  I used the wrong word.  Sec on your question.

Comment: @VictorStone I consider the lambda to be a good description of what is going on there, better than abstracting it out?  I mean, even a call to `add_to_sum(&sum, myObj, &MyBaseObj::DoSomething, number1, number2)` is not much shorter than the lambda I wrote, and it obscures what is going on.  You can even shorten the lambda down to `[=,&sum]{ sum += myObj->DoSomething(number1, number2); }` if you really want to.  I like being explicit what my async lambdas capture, however.

Comment: I mean like so: `std::function<unsigned int(unsigned int, double)> doSomethingFunction = std::bind( &MyBaseObj::DoSomething, myObj, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 );` and using it in the lambda

Comment: Surely you'd be much using a promise/future pair for this, rather than having `sum` take on its value god-knows-when?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, they could just join the `thread`s.

Comment: Yakk, I do get a warning when trying to capture "myObj" because i actually have it declared at a more broad scope. "warning: capture of variable ‘myObj’ with non-automatic storage duration". @Lightness I dont know the concept of promises/futures very well. I'll research them a bit to try to use them in this case. (I am joining the threads currently, this is the reason for keeping them in the vector)

Comment: @VictorStone If it is global (ick), then you don't need to capture it.  Stop using global variables.  If it is a member variable, capture `this` (and ensure lifetime).  If you cannot ensure lifetime, create a local copy & capture it (C++11), or do a capture-statement (C++14).

Comment: Yakk, I'm curious. If the lambda and std::function were declared already. What would be the syntax to emplace it into the thread? Assuming C++11, 14, or even 17 where the compiler correctly implemented it.

Comment: @VictorStone ... no difference?  `std::move` is an option, if you want to avoid copying.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @VictorStone have you tried creating a lambda or a `std::function`, and `emplace_back`ing it into a `vector<std::thread>`?  When you did so, what did you try?  What went wrong?

Comment: I tried once more and managed to get the syntax correct. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before. Check out the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

After trying again I managed to get the syntax correct.

```
std::function<unsigned int(unsigned int, double)> myObjDoSomethingFunc =
    std::bind(&MyBaseObj::DoSomething, myObj, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
unsigned int someNum1 = 234;
double someNum2 = 238.239;
auto doSomethingLambda = [someNum, &sum](std::function<unsigned int(unsigned int, double)> doSomethingFunc, double param2) {
    sum += doSomethingFunc(someNum,param2);
};
myThreads.emplace_back(doSomethingLambda,myObjDoSomethingFunc,someNum2);
```